# Retirar números ao final de uma string Regex C#

Tags: c#, regex

Tenho uma string que contem o nome de alguns registros.

Exemplos :

```
string nome = "MARIA APARECIDA DE SOUZA MOURA 636598241";
string nome = "MARIA APARECIDA DE SOUZA MOURA 2018";
```

Gostaria de retirar os números somente quando estiverem no final do texto e onde a quantidade de caracteres numéricos seja superior a 4.

***Exemplos:***

> `MARIA APARECIDA DE SOUZA MOURA 636598241` **ficaria:** `MARIA APARECIDA DE SOUZA MOURA`

e

> `MARIA APARECIDA DE SOUZA MOURA 2017` **sem alteração pois só contem 4 caracteres numéricos**

Fiz algumas tentativas com o `Regex`, mas até agora sem sucesso

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Para extrair os números no final da string utilize o Regex `@"\d+$"`
- Verifique se o resultado de caracteres da string é maior do que `4`
- Utilize `Replace` e substituia por nada.

<sub>[**Veja funcionando no dotnetfiddle.**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lvzPKr)</sub>

```
string nome = "MARIA APARECIDA DE SOUZA MOURA 6365945";
    
var numeros = Regex.Match(nome, @"\d+$").Value;
    
nome = numeros.Length > 4 ? nome = nome.Replace(numeros,"") : nome;
```

## Lendo a regex

`\d` é um *shortHand* que é um atalho para o conjunto `[0-9]`, ou seja, busca valores numéricos.

`+` é um *quantificador* que procura um ou mais elementos, é o mesmo que `{1,}`

`$` é uma *borda* que busca no final do texto

Outra maneira que segue a mesma linha de pensamento: <sup>[dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ic5hdT)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar a expressão **`\d+$`**, ela tenta encontrar quaisquer dígitos que estejam no final da *string*.

Construindo uma instância de `Regex` com esta expressão, você pode validar o tamanho da *substring* que foi encontrada e então fazer a substituição se esta string que foi encontrada **tiver mais de 4 caracteres**.

Veja um exemplo:

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{   
    public static string Remover4DigitosFinais(string input)
    {   
        var expressao = new Regex(@"\d+$");     
        var r = expressao.Match(input);     
        return r.Length > 4 ? expressao.Replace(input, "").TrimEnd() : input;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var validacoes = new [] 
        {
            new { Input = "MARIA 2 APARECIDA DE SOUZA MOURA 636598241", Esperado = "MARIA 2 APARECIDA DE SOUZA MOURA" },
            new { Input = "MARIA 2 APARECIDA DE SOUZA MOURA 2018", Esperado = "MARIA 2 APARECIDA DE SOUZA MOURA 2018" },
            new { Input = "JOAO 175", Esperado = "JOAO 175" },
            new { Input = "JOAO 1751233", Esperado = "JOAO" },
        };

        foreach(var val in validacoes)
        {
            var novo = Remover4DigitosFinais(val.Input);            
            var sucesso = (novo == val.Esperado);

            WriteLine($"Sucesso: {sucesso} - Entrada: {val.Input} - Saída: {novo} - Esperado: {val.Esperado}");
        }           
    }   
}
```

<sup>[**Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle.**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MjfARJ)</sup>

Isso com certeza é ótimo se você quiser tirar a responsabilidade da regex e, consequentemente, ter uma expressão mais curta e mais fácil de entender.

Caso contrário, você pode simplesmente usar a expressão **`(\s\d{5,})+$`**, ela tenta encontrar qualquer *substring* onde o primeiro carácter seja um espaço (`\s`), depois deste espaço existam dígitos (`\d`), que estejam no final da *string* principal (`$`) desde que esta combinação tenha tamanho maior que cinco (`{5,}`).

```
public static string Remover4DigitosFinais(string input)
{   
    var expressao = new Regex(@"(\s\d{5,})+$");             
    return expressao.Replace(input, "");
}
```

<sup>[**Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle.**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qrl67X)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

A busca pelo fim seria `+$` com a busca de números com maior de 4 digitos `[0-9]{5,}`, e a expressão final também verificando o espaço: `"(\\s[0-9]{5,})+$"`:

```
string nome0 = "0 - MARIA APARECIDA DE SOUZA MOURA 636598241";
string nome1 = "1 - MARIA APARECIDA DE SOUZA MOURA 2018";
string nome2 = "2 - MARIA APARECIDA DE SOUZA 636598241 MOURA";

string strRegex = "(\\s[0-9]{5,})+$";

string resu0 = Regex.Replace(nome0, strRegex, "");
string resu1 = Regex.Replace(nome1, strRegex, "");
string resu2 = Regex.Replace(nome2, strRegex, "");
```

- [Exemplo ONLINE Ideone](https://ideone.com/2fkAR4)
- [Exemplo ONLINE dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yLrKOZ)

Answer (score 1):

Uma dica é usar um caracter como separador e utilizar a função .slip() transformando sua string em uma array, dessa forma vc tem liberdade de pegar o nome, ou apenas o numero a qualquer momento com maio facilidade.

Exemplo:

```
string nomeNumero = "MARIA APARECIDA DE SOUZA MOURA | 636598241";
string nome = nomeNumero.Split("|")[0];
string numero = nomeNumero.Split("|")[1];
```